# Is there a way to set different permissions to pipelines and datasets in the same Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, data-science, azure-data-factory, azure-cloud-services, azure-rbac

I'm trying to set RBAC to the components of a Data Factory so every different user group can work just with the pipeline they have to. Is there a way to achieve this?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of the [built in roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles). I don't see what you are looking for exactly. It might be worth looking at creating a custom role specific for what you are looking for.

Most likely would need to build a custom role looking at which [features of Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.datafactory/2018-06-01/factories/dataflows) you'd like to grant permissions to.

And then [create a custom role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles) which can be deploy via ARM or Powershell.